# RestClient::SSLCertificateNotVerified error when trying to create a simple POST request

Tags: ruby, api, ssl, ssl-certificate, rest-client

I am learning Ruby and trying to learn how to use rest-client to make API calls. I am using Foobot's API (found here: https://api.foobot.io) because it is really simple and open.

Here is the full error message I'm getting:

```
#<RestClient::SSLCertificateNotVerified: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed>
```

Here is my code (with sample data inserted of course).

[image]

This is the Authentication POST request. I am able to successfully complete this request in Postman without any additional things like an SSL certificate. I just have my username, password, and API key. The API documentation doesn't mention anything about SSL certificates. It just says that they strongly recommend using HTTPS, which I am here. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what version of ruby are you using? Different versions of ruby have different SSL encryptions included.

Comment: ruby -v 

ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295)

Comment: Can you please post your code in a code block instead of an image?

Comment: @Impulso did you ever resolve this issue? Can you share some information?

Comment: Finally I found the solution to my certificate issues: running `rvm osx-ssl-certs update all` solved it for me immediately. Found it here: https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/issues/288